# Json.Net with [WebMethod]s

Tags: json.net, webmethod

I'm trying to swap out the Json formatter to Json.Net, so I can get ISO dates instead of "/Date(1379112467317)/"

I'm also letting .Net (WebForms) auto-magically handle Json serialization/deserialization through [WebMethod]s.  Which don't seem to be using the Json.Net formatter.

In my global.asax, I can see the old MS Json formatter getting removed, and the new Json.net formatter added with the IsoDateTimeConverter.

But, my [Webmethod]s still come back with the old /Date()/ json strings instead of Iso dates.  Do I have to do anything special in my global.asax for [Webmethod]s auto-magic to use the new formatter?

Here's the code in global:

As seen in: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

```
var formatter = config.Formatters.Where(f => { return f.SupportedMediaTypes.Any(v => v.MediaType.Equals("application/json", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)); }).FirstOrDefault();

if (formatter != null)
{                    
    config.Formatters.Remove(formatter);
}

JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonNetFormatter(serializerSettings));
```

Comment: how do you know the formatter is getting called and is your response marked as application/json response or not in the webform?

Comment: I'm not sure if my formatter is getting called when WebMethods are called.  Do you know how to tell?  I only know so far that the old one is getting removed, and the new one is getting added, by stepping through it in App_Start.  The response coming over the wire is JSON (rather than say XML).

Answer (score 0):

I think the way that you setup the formatter looks fine for me. but how do you make sure it is being use in the webform returns, it doesn't happen automatically.

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
public Something GetSomething()
{

}

how about you try that.

Comment: It actually happens automatically.  Definitely getting JSON back, this is a pretty mature app.  Added that in for kicks, same result, which is /Date()/.  Maybe I need to configure the Json.net somewhere else to get it to return Iso Dates?  The examples seemed to show just newing up IsoDateTimeConverter(), and stepping through it seems to pick up an ISO string format inside the formatter above.  Just not getting applied in web methods automagically.